# Spring tool Suite Strange icons in the tool bar

Tags: eclipse, spring, ide, spring-tool-suite

I am seeing these strange icons in my IDE for last so many days. These icons are all disabled. Initially, there were only few of them but now the tool bar is full of these icons. Mouse over on any of them says - "Open PHP Type"

[image]

I would like to know how to remove these and is it slowing down my STS.

Thanks,
Tarun

Comment: Since those icons are related to the PHP tooling (which is not related to STS and isn't part of STS by default), I would recommend to uninstall the PHP tooling from STS. I guess that removes those icons, too.

Comment: Right click the perspective icon `Spring` and select `Customize...`. Try to find those items in `Tool Bar visibility` or `Action Set Availability` tab.
If you find them, just uncheck the items to hide them.